# How can I zero out weak elements near stronger ones in a matrix?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, distance, vectorization

I have a pixel matrix containing some points and a lot of zero elements. From those non-zero points, I want to discard those that have a stronger point in range N withing the matrix. The range is an euclidean distance between the pixels.

```
input  = [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.9 0.0 0.0 
          0.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.5 
          0.0 0.0 0.7 0.0 0.0 0.0 
          0.0 0.4 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0];

output = [0.0 0.0 0.0 0.9 0.0 0.0   % 0.7 is the largest number in range
          0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5   % 0.2 got removed; was next to 0.9 and 0.7
          0.0 0.0 0.7 0.0 0.0 0.0   % 0.7 is the largest number in range
          0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0]; % 0.1 and 0.4 both got removed; were next to 0.7
```

**Update:** This is what I've came up so far. It iterates over all non-zero pixels and compares the current pixel to the largest of the neighborhood. However, the neighborhood contains to many pixels. Rather than selecting the area through index offsets, I need to select a circular area somehow. Moreover, I'd be grateful if there is a shorter way, maybe replacing the loops with built-in Matlab functions like `conv2` or `imfilter`.

```
% Discard points near stronger points
points = find(Image > 0);
radius = args.Results.min_dist;
for i = 1:size(points)
    [index_y, index_x] = ind2sub(size(Image), points(i));
    %  Find neighborhood
    from_x = max(index_x-radius, 1);
    from_y = max(index_y-radius, 1);
    to_x = min(index_x+radius, size(Image, 2));
    to_y = min(index_y+radius, size(Image, 1));
    neighbors = Image(from_y:to_y, from_x:to_x);
    % Discard if there is a stronger neighbor
    largest = max(max(neighbors));
    if Image(index_y, index_x) < largest
        Image(index_y, index_x) = 0;
    end
end
```

Comment: How do you define that "stronger point"?

Comment: @Divakar By stronger point, I was just referring to larger values in pixel matrix.

Comment: Well that's what I was referring as to how you define "strong" and "weak" here.  I guessing there must be some weighting criteria here for that.

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: @Divakar They're ordered just by their value. So a pixel of `0.7` is larger or stronger than a pixel of value `0.3`, because 0.7 > 0.3. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @TryHard No, I haven't.

Comment: Do you have Statistics Toolbox?

Comment: @mehmet I want to keep pixels below 0.3 if there are only smaller pixels (or no pixels at all) within their euclidean distance of N.

Comment: @Divakar No, I only have the standard functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `basic workflow` to solve this problem could be described as discussed below -

1. Sort all the non-zero points.
2. Start with the highest valued point and set all non-zeros points within its N-neighbourhood to zeros.
3. Do the same for the second highest one and set all non-zeros points within its N-neighbourhood to zeros **excluding the non-zero points with higher value than the current one**. This excluding part could be implemented with a very useful MATLAB tool `triu` inside the codes.
4. Continue till every non-zero point is covered. Of course, as we move down this ladder, there will be lesser points to search for, because of the **excluding clause** discussed earlier.

These steps could be implemented with a vectorized approach, using no *special* toolboxes and assuming `A` as the input -

```
%// Distance parameter
N = 2; 

%// Find all non-zero points and then sort them in descending manner
[x,y] = find(A~=0)
pts = [x y]
[val,sorted_idx] = sort(A(A~=0),'descend')
pts = pts(sorted_idx,:)

%// Find euclidean distances
distmat = sqrt(squared_dist(pts,pts))

%// Find points to be removed (set to zero); then calculate their linear indices
rm_pts = pts(any(triu(distmat<N,1),1),:)
rm_lin_idx = sub2ind(size(A),rm_pts(:,1),rm_pts(:,2))

%// Use those linear indices to set those in the input as zeros
out = A;
out(rm_lin_idx) = 0;
```

Associated function code (to find squared euclidean distances) -

```
function sq_distmat = squared_dist(A,B)

[nA,dim] = size(A);
nB = size(B,1);

A_ext = ones(nA,dim*3);
A_ext(:,2:3:end) = -2*A;
A_ext(:,3:3:end) = A.^2;

B_ext = ones(nB,dim*3);
B_ext(:,1:3:end) = B.^2;
B_ext(:,2:3:end) = B;

sq_distmat = A_ext * B_ext.';

return;
```

Code run -

```
A =
         0         0         0    0.9000         0         0
         0         0    0.2000         0         0    0.5000
         0         0    0.7000         0         0         0
         0    0.4000    0.1000         0         0         0
out =
         0         0         0    0.9000         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0    0.5000
         0         0    0.7000         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Spent a while looking for use of `max` ... took me a moment to wrap my head around the alternative combination of `sort`, `triu` and `any`... really elegant!

Comment: @TryHard Thanks! That really was one of the trickiest things with the solution I think! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you had the image processing toolbox installed (or one of the free alternatives mentioned in [*Try Hard*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28408349/3139711)), you could make this happen quite easily:

The function `imdilate` is basically a sliding max filter. So what we do is, for each pixel we look for the maximum in the neighborhood specified by your radius `R`. Then we compare the actual value with the found maximum and if it is smaller, we set the value to zero.

```
function A = zeroOutWeakElements(A, R)
[X,Y] = ndgrid(-ceil(R):ceil(R));
neighborhood = (X.^2 + Y.^2)<=R^2;
A(imdilate(A,neighborhood)>A) = 0;
```

For large full matrices and small distances this would also be significantly faster than the currently accepted solution. The benefit will wear off with sparse matrices and large radii, but I guess you should test with actual data to be sure what's best.

Comment: Very elegant solution to use morphology! +1

Answer (score 1):

There are various freely available substitutes for `MATLAB` image processing toolbox functions; for instance you can look into `octave`, or if that does not suit you see e.g. [this source](http://algoholic.eu/partial-replacement-for-matlabs-image-processing-toolbox/) although it requires mex compilation.

You are looking for a filter with an abrupt cutoff. Filters are a standard tool in the toolbox. Start by looking at the documentation of tools like `imfilter` and perhaps `imdilate` and `imopen`.

Comment: @danijar you can specify your own kernel with `fspecial`